# Как изменить свойства json с помощью настраиваемых атрибутов?

Tags: c#, сериализация, атрибуты

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [MyPropertyInfo(SerializationName = "Имя сотрудника")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MyPropertyInfo(SerializationName = "Опыт работы")]
        public int Experience { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class MyPropertyInfoAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string SerializationName { get; set; }
    }


    public class MySerializer<T>
    {
        private T _obj;

        public MySerializer(T obj)
        {
            _obj = obj;
        }

        public string Serialize()
        {
            string serializedEmployee = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_obj);
            return serializedEmployee;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee { Name = "Ivanov Ivan", Experience = 5 };
            MySerializer<Employee> employeeSerializer = new MySerializer<Employee>(employee);
            string serializedEmployee = employeeSerializer.Serialize();
            Console.WriteLine(serializedEmployee);
        }
    }
```

На выходе сериализованная строка должна выйти Имя сотрудника Ivanov Ivan Опыт работы 5 
У меня название свойств остались без изменений

Comment: А зачем вам свой собственный атрибут? Ведь есть готовые для этого (`JsonProperty("")` если json.net или `JsonProjertyName("")` если System.Text.Json). И да, делать русские названия для свойств - весьма плохая практика...

Comment: В тз написано через настраиваемые атрибуты, а насчет название свойств не знаю почему так

Comment: Стандартные атрибуты, тоже настраиваемые, можете указать любое имя свойства. Так что, как по мне, это не оправдание. Если вам говорят в задание допустим "распарсить самостоятельно JSON", то зачем вы тогда берете и делаете обертку над готовым компонентом, коверкая все там? Вот зачем класс `MySerializer`, если это просто `JsonSerializer.Serialize`..? Короче, мне совсем не понять этот код и ваше задание, оно очень, очень странное, советую уточнить у преподавателя что именно от вас хотят.

Comment: Где тз? Вы уверены, что правильно его поняли?

Comment: Сериализатор понимает только свои собственные атрибуты. `JsonSerializer` ничего не знает о `MyPropertyInfoAttribute` и, соответственно, не умеет его использовать. Поэтому нужно либо использовать атрибуты, которые сериализатор понимает (см. первый комментарий), либо писать собственный сериализатор.